# Server caching IIS6

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-6, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to use Server Caching on Windows IIS6?

I know it is a feature of IIS7, but is there a way to use server caching on IIS6? Maybe there is some additional software?

I would like to use server cache for pages that need a lot of SQL Database connections, but where the data doesn't change that much. So for semi-dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Use the [@OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) directive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is the cache for every user different or see all the users the same cached page?